# How to determine the argument number order of one VI?

Tags: labview

I got some error like "error from Property Node (arg 8) in VISA Configure Serial Port." How to know which arg is arg 8?, which is arg 1 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is flow control.

> Specifies the flow control method used for both transmitting and receiving data. Valid values include: (0) Flow None, (1) Flow XON/XOFF, (2) Flow RTS/CTS, (3) Flow XON/XOFF and RTS/CTS, (4) Flow DTR/DSR, (5) Flow XON/XOFF and DTR/DSR. Certain values or combinations of values may not be supported by all serial ports and/or operating systems.
>
> **(0) None—Does** not use flow control, and buffers on both sides of the connection are assumed to be large enough to hold all data transferred.
>
> **(1) XON/XOFF**—Uses the XON and XOFF characters to perform flow control. The transfer mechanism controls input flow by sending XOFF when the low-level I/O receive buffer is nearly full, and it controls the output flow by suspending transmission when XOFF is received.
>
> **(2) RTS/CTS**—Uses the RTS output signal and the CTS input signal to perform flow control. The transfer mechanism controls input flow by unasserting the RTS signal when the low-level I/O receive buffer is nearly full, and it controls output flow by suspending the transmission when the CTS signal is unasserted.
>
> **(3) XON/XOFF and RTS/CTS**—Uses both values 1 & 2.
>
> **(4) DTR/DSR**—Uses the DTR output signal and the DSR input signal to perform flow control. The transfer mechanism controls input flow by unasserting the DTR signal when the low-level I/O receive buffer is nearly full, and it controls output flow by suspending the transmission when the DSR signal is unasserted.
>
> **(5) XON/XOFF and DTR/DSR**—Uses both values 4 & 5.

Please have a look on the picture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that does not answer my question. My question is how to aquire the map between arg(1,2,3..) and the specific args, including all other VIs. The help documents does not state the arg numbering.

Comment: I got the same picture as yours except the number(123...89), do you know how to make them displayed as yours?

Comment: I wrote them using paint, you can not display them, just keep in mind that arguments in default NI visa properties are set by right order from up to down. And Errors display accordingly.